# cluster 2d matrix (clustring) with kmeans

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix, cluster-analysis, k-means

i have a 2d Matrix and It contains specifications for laptops, where each group contains three components like thant :

```
[['8 gigabytes', 'Intel 9th Generation Core i7', '512 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 9th Generation Core i7', '1000 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 10th Generation Core i7', '512 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 9th Generation Core i7', '1256 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 10th Generation Core i7', '512 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 9th Generation Core i7', '512 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 9th Generation Core i7', '512 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 9th Generation Core i7', '512 gigabytes']]
```

Where I want to collect and classify this data according to three factors (gaming, casual, business) using kmeans or anyting else .
[image]
can someone help me with that .thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

That looks like a list of lists. Try to parse it like this.

```
sub = [sub_list[0] for sub_list in documents]
```

Then, do your clustering.